# What's the possibility of random guessing a youtube's video ID

Tags: random-number-generator

Let's say i make a program that produces an eleven character long ID like youtube does and tries to find a valid video in youtube. What's the actual possibility that it's going to produce a valid ID corresponding to a real video and also an unlisted one??

Comment: I don't see how this is connected to CS. It is about probability theory.

Comment: Why don't you run the experiment and see? Note that it depends on the exact encoding scheme used (whether it is an error-correcting code) as well as the current number of videos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Each YouTube id consists of 11 characters denoted by $v = [v_1, ··· ,
> v_{11}]$. 
>   The first $10$ characters of a valid id contain any of the characters
>   in $S = \{0 − 9,\_, −, A − Z, a − z\}$, i.e., $v_i ∈ S (i =
> 1, ··· , 10)$. The last (11-th) character $v_{11}$ only comes from $T =
> \{0, 4, 8, A, E, I,M, Q, U, Y, c, g, k, o, s, w\}$, namely, $v_{11} \in T 1$.
>   The size of video id space is, therefore, $64^{10}\cdot16$.
>
> We also observe that YouTube video ids are not generated in any sequence. Instead,
>   YouTube picks an unused random id from this pool for each new
>   video that is uploaded.
>
> **Source: http://conferences.sigcomm.org/imc/2011/docs/p371.pdf**

For instance, they show that YouTube video is randomly generated from the id
space and that the entire YouTube id space can be represented as $S = S^{10} × T$, where:

- $S = \{0−9,\_, −, A−Z, a−z\}$
- $T = \{0, 4, 8, A, E, I,M,Q, U, Y, c, g, k, o, s, w\}$.

Their estimation of the total number of youtube videos is $502\cdot10^6$.

Given these 2 information (video id space and estimation of the total number of videos) you can deduce the probability that, given an id of $11$ characters in $S^{10} × T$, it corresponds to the id of a valid video.

Comment: Typo: the id space is $64^{10} \cdot 16$ (i.e. $2^{60} \cdot 16$ ... a 64 bit integer)

Comment: you're right, fixed